# How to return a value using context.executeQueryAsync?

Tags: javascript

How can I get this function to return the value?  In all the examples I have seen, folks use an `alert` in the delegate functions, but I need to return the value instead.  When I call the function, it fetches me my default string, which means the `executeQueryAsync` is not setting the variable.

What am I doing wrong?

```
var thisuser = SPGetSPcurrentUser();
alert(thisuser);
//-------------------------------------------------------------------
var SPGetSPcurrentUser = function(){
    var spuserid = "Error";
    var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    this.website = context.get_web();
    this.currentUser = website.get_currentUser();
    context.load(currentUser);
    context.executeQueryAsync(
        function(sender, args){ this.spuserid = currentUser.get_loginName();},
        function(sender, args){ this.spuserid = 'request failed ' + args.get_message() + '\n'+ args.get_stackTrace();}
    )
    return spuserid;
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As the method [`executeQueryAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff411085(v=office.14).aspx) indicates it is asynchronous.
You can actually force the XMLHttpRequest to be [synchronous](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests), although that is beside the point.

What you are looking for is a callback function, something like this:

```
var getSpCurrentUser = function(callback) {
  var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
  var user = ctx.get_web().get_currentUser();

  ctx.load(user);
  ctx.executeQueryAsync(function() {
    callback(null, user);
  }, function(a, b) {
    callback(new Error(b.get_message()));
  });
};

getSpCurrentUser(function(error, user) {
  if (error) {
    console.error(error);
    return;
  }
  console.log(user.get_title());
});
```

Comment: Thanks, Erik.  I've only ever used a callback function once or twice in my life.  I don't understand where anything returns the value.  Also, could you explain to me how there can be two functions with the same name?  (Sorry for being dense)

Comment: The value is not returned, instead you pass a function into the `getSpCurrentUser` as a variable (line 13 and 1, named _callback_) which will be called from within the `getSpCurrentUser` function (line 7 and 9). Since `executeQueryAsync` is asynchronous any code after line 19 will be run before you get your callback (line 14-18). There should not be two functions with the same name

Comment: So the first instance of `getSpCurrentUser` is just a variable, and the second instance, being a `callback` is really just an extension of the variable?  So, to actually call the `callback` function, I would just use "callback"?

Comment: I think I don't need the executeQuery to be Async.  Is there a way to return the query within the same thread?  I realize that would make the script wait.

Comment: This is the way you are suppose to do it. When dealing with AJAX this is the common approach. You can get around this by augmenting XMLHttpRequest, but that is _very bad_ :)

Comment: So, from my original code, where is it that I can get the value into the `thisuser` variable?  I think I am still missing something.

Comment: I have tried to keep your code as similar as your original one, while also trying to follow some best practices (jshinting), you can see the result here: https://gist.github.com/4241236

Comment: I thank you for that, and I appreciate your time (as well as the "jshinting", honestly I do), but it is necessary that I somehow *return* the value from `SPGetSPcurrentUser`. I could get it into an alert using the original code.

Comment: With executeQueryAsync it is impossible. I believe you can do it with [SPServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=$().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser&referringTitle=Documentation). See [example](http://spservices.codeplex.com/discussions/207059#PostContent_422723)

Answer (score 1):

This is the closest I've found to returning a variable reference for the logged-on user.

Try it out it's simple to test:
 1. In IE browse to your SharePoint site, open developer tools press (f12)
 2. Open the Console press (ctl + 2) 
 3. Switch line-mode with your cursor in the "Console input" press (ctl + alt + m) 
 4. Paste all the following contents into the console then press (ctl + enter)

```
function iWannaDoSomethingWith(thisUser){
 if(thisUser === null){
  alert('failed to get user');
 }
 else{
  alert('User name:' + thisUser.get_title() 
  + '\n Login Name:' + thisUser.get_loginName());
 }
}
function necessaryEvilToWireItAllTogether(nameOfFuncWeReallyWantToCall){
 if (typeof(nameOfFuncWeReallyWantToCall)==="function")
 {
  var ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
  var oWeb = ctx.get_web();
  var currentUser = oWeb.get_currentUser();
  currentUser.retrieve();
  ctx.load(oWeb);
  ctx.executeQueryAsync(
   function(){
    // successful Async call
    nameOfFuncWeReallyWantToCall(currentUser);
   },
   function(){
    // failed Async call
    nameOfFuncWeReallyWantToCall(null);
   }
  );    
 }
}
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function(){necessaryEvilToWireItAllTogether(iWannaDoSomethingWith);}, "sp.js");
```